# Adding to BlackoutDates using SelectedDate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

A small demo program is included below. To reproduce the problem, select a date and click the "BlackoutDate" button. On my system I get an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CalendarBlackoutDate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Calendar Name="calendar"/>
        <Button Name="blackoutDateButton" Content="BlackoutDate" Click="blackoutDateButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CalendarBlackoutDate
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void blackoutDateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            calendar.BlackoutDates.Add(
                new CalendarDateRange(
                    calendar.SelectedDate.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of calendar.SelectedDate.Value

Also, please post a stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same calendar for the selected date as the blackout??  Selected date cannot be blackout date.

```
 calendar1.BlackoutDates.Add(
            new CalendarDateRange(
                calendar2.SelectedDate.Value));

<Calendar Name="calendar1"/>
<Calendar Name="calendar2"/>
```

If one calendar

```
if (calendar1.SelectedDate == null) return;
DateTime dtBO = (DateTime)calendar1.SelectedDate;
calendar1.SelectedDate = null;
calendar1.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(dtBO));
```

Comment: Thanks Blam. I'd like to avoid having two separate calendars. Perhaps I can save the selected date, unselect the date, and then add it to the blackout date.

Comment: Your updated answer solves the problem perfectly. Thanks Blam!